# Java WAR deployment issue

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, war

I've built a basic Java Web Project using Netbeaans, which uses Maven.

The issue is, in my 'dependencies' I see 'javaee-web-api-6.0.jar'. However, when I build the project, in the .war file I don't see this .jar file included anywhere.

Am I missing something, or is there any extra step that I need to take to have all the dependencies be included in the .jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlet API dependencies should *never* be in the resulting war file. It is a dependency that is provided by your container. Having it in the war file would only result in a bunch of classloader issues. Most containers would ignore the jar file anyway, if it was present inside the war.

Comment: So is Java EE 6.0 provided by Tomcat?

Comment: thanks. is there any downside to including the javaee-web-api-6.0.jar in the WEB-INF/lib directory of the war?

Comment: There are no benefits of adding it. As I said, most containers would ignore it, but if it doesn't, it would just cause a lot of classloading headaches. You don't need it there, so don't add it.

Comment: I don't see java ee in my tomcat 7.0's lib directory, so it doesn't seem like this jar is present in tomcat by default

Comment: Trust me, Tomcat bundles the JEE web classes, under one name or another. You won't find the full JEE API there though, since it's only a web container, not a full JEE server. Maybe you should try explaining what the exact problem you're having is?

Comment: The issue is, Netbeans is not creating a web.xml file, and apparently one isn't needed for Java EE 6. Which is nice, but I'm concerned that if I built it on EE 6 and then send the war to production to be deployed on the server, if it doesn't have EE 6 then it might not run. Any ideas?

Comment: Hopefully, you'll be able to verify that it's working _before_ sending it to production. But if it does not run, it's definetively not because it doesn't have the web apis in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: To put it this way: If the web container is not providing the web api classes, then it's not a web container, and won't be able to run the war anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I guess you're right, including the .jar causes it to break for me locally. And it works for me without the jar on Tomcat 7 locally, so it should work on the server for the same tomcat as well, hopefully. right?

Comment: Yes, if something fails, it's because of something else.

Answer (score 1):

Check the scope of javaee-web-api-6.0.jar dependency. If its **provided** then it will not be bundled into the resultant war.

Comment: If it's `provided`, it will _not_ be bundled, which is what is correct.

Comment: @NilsH sorry a typo mistake that is what i wanted to say. Corrected the type.

Answer (score 0):

`javaee-api-6.0.jar and servlet-api-3.jar` These jars are already provided by Tomcat(assuming using tomact). To verify this look in `<TOMCAT_HOME>\lib` to see that these jars are already there.

Comment: I have Tomcat 7.0 and looking in its lib directory, I don't see the `javaee-api-6.0.jar' file there. I do see `servlet-api.jar`

Comment: @NilsH No it isn't, the java EE doesn't seem to be included with tomcat, only servlets seem to be.

Comment: Can you please add javaee jar ti web-inf/lib,and see what happens ?

Comment: `java-ee-web-api` and `servlet-api` is basically the same. You won't find the full `jee` api though, since Tomcat is only a web container. It's not a full JEE server with EJBs and everything.

Comment: @Baadshah What should Adding the full JEE jar to tomcat libs be good for?

Comment: @NilsH I said web-inf/lib not to tomacat lib.